# How to force Jenkins to build dependencies first

Tags: maven, jenkins

We have a bunch of Maven Jenkins projects, some of them dependant on others.
Jenkins figures out the upstream/downstream automatically.

We might have a situation like:

```
Project A
|_ Project B
   |_Project C
```

meaning that A has B as dependency and B has C as dependency.

Often happens that if I push changes to A, B and C at the same time, A might start building first, without having the changes that were pushed at the same time to B or C, causing the build to fail.

Eventually B and C will build and they will re-trigger the build of A, so that A will go green, but I was wondering if there was a way to avoid these temporary failures.

I thought that the `quiet time` could help in this matter, but it looks like this is useful only to not trigger multiple builds on the same project in case multiple pushes are done in a short period of time. I was hoping instead that it would delay the build for x seconds and at the end of it would analyse the queue and figure out what should be built first.

Is there anything built in Jenkins which helps for this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give you a work around.
Provide `quiet time` as `5` or `10`. Now Configure for `Project A` -> `Block build when upstream project is building`. So with the `quiet time` the `Project A` job will wait for `5` or `10` seconds. As you said you will be pushing the changes to `Project B & C` at the same time, Now the builds will be started for these projects. And now when `Project A` resumes, because of this option `Block build when upstream project is building`, it won't build. So same do between the `Project B & C` also. Hope this helps.

I have got another solution. This might help you also. Choose as per your requirement.

 `Build after other projects are built` use this option and choose `Trigger only if build is stable` option. So that it won't build if this project if the dependencies fails. Hope this helps.

Comment: Can't see the `Block build when downstream project is building` option. I can only see `Block build if certain jobs are running` but that is a text area where you're supposed to specify manually the jobs, which defeats the purpose of having the auto downstream discovery for maven projects.

Comment: I have already the `Trigger only if build is stable` option enabled. The problem is not that the job gets triggered when a dependency fails, the problem is that the job gets triggered alongside the dependency. It's like Jenkins does not look at the queue content to decide which one to start first.

Comment: [Check this image](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CWlDLlIwTjnh9YH0cbxLrVl9tQ_GoTw9) for `Block build when downstream project is building`

Comment: As you've set up your project upstream/downstream method, if you can see `Block build when downstream project is building` option under `General` -> `Advanced`, then the build will be stopped as per my solution. Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, in advanced I have `Block build when upstream project is building` checked for project A, which is what we want I think. In fact B is upstream of A. So I think we want to say to block on upstream builds rather than downstreams. This works in the sense that if I kick Project B and then I kick project A, A waits until B is finished. The problem presents when there are concurrent commits to both projects, and in the quiet time Jenkins can't figure out which one to start with.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164265/discussion-between-sv-madhava-reddy-and-supercalifragilistichespirali).

Comment: It turns out that the problem was linked to webhooks. The git push triggers a webhook registered in gitlab, and such url did not have `delay` query param specified. All the projects were setup with a quiet period but it looks like if a webhook is triggered with a url not specifying delay, then Jenkins assumes it's 0, so it starts the job immediately. Adding `delay=5sec` fixed the issue. Can you edit your response suggesting to enable `Block build when upstream project is building` rather than `Block build when downstream project is building` so that I can accept your answer? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume your jobs A,B and C are getting triggered because of push/commits.
How about configuring a wrapper job which gets triggered on push/commit and that job will determine which downstream job(s) to execute and in which order based on the commits done?

Comment: I would really like to avoid adding any wrapping job, since Jenkins should have the information to behave in the correct way.